How can I add font name, font size, and "insert symbol" to the Excel 365 Quick Access Toolbar on Mac?
I'm moving from Excel 2010 on Windows to Excel 365 on Mac, and I'm trying to replicate my Quick Access Toolbar (QAT) commands. I've been mostly successful, but I can't find a way to add the Font Name, Font Size, and Insert Symbol (or the apparently equivalent [Edit Menu]>Emoji & Symbols) commands to Excel 365's QAT on Mac. Can someone tell me how?
Having refined my QAT over many years under Windows, I know that these are commands I will frequently want to access, so I'd really like to get them on the QAT.
Thanks.
